# Kali Linux ARP Spoofing Not Working

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I am using the following commands:

```
sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 [victim ip] -r [default gateway]
sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 [default gateway] -r [victim ip]
```

The only thing that happens is that I get continuous arp replies, but the victim's machine still works. How do I fix this?

Comment: do you know what is the goal of an arp spoofing attack ? goal is not to "destroy" the attacked machine...

Comment: Don't get technical on me. Of course I know what arpspoofing is supposed to do. It is supposed to kill the connection. That's what I meant.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to ask at all. We cannot guess what you meant or are thinking, please take some time aside to write clearer questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `arpspoof` command does not aim to kill a connection.

It's usually used to force all traffic for the victim machine via your own so that you can sniff the traffic.

In order to do this it has to send a continuous stream of faked ARP requests so that it can trick other machines on the LAN into talking to your own machine rather than the real target.

You might want to check [man arpspoof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/arpspoof).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, the redirection is often used to cut the connection on the targeted device in the LAN as seen with many arpspoof clients such as ettercap and netattack master. My question is why am I only getting arp replies as opposed to some of my other Kali linux machines that arp spoof just fine and how can I fix it.

Comment: @MattHerrada, if traffic is being redirected from/to the victim via your Kali system it sounds like it's working just fine. If not, you need to update your question to make this clear.